# Autoform afArrayField invalid field name

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using Autoform in my Meteor app with the following schema:

```
Projects = new Mongo.Collection('Projects');
Projects.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Project Title"
},
tiles: {
    type: [Object],
    label: "Tiles",
    optional: true
},
"tiles.$": {
    type: Array,
    optional: true
},
"tiles.$.description": {
    type: String,
    label: "Tile Description",
    optional: true
}
}));
```

In my template I have the following custom autoForm:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Projects" doc=this id="updateProjectInfo" type="update"}}
  {{> afQuickField name="title"}}
  {{> afArrayField name="tiles" template="AdminEditTile"}}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

And then the template for the afArrayField:

```
<template name="afArrayField_AdminEditTile">
  {{> afFormGroup name="this.current.description"}}
</template>
```

However I'm receiving an error in the browser `Exception in template helper: Error: Invalid field name: this.current.description`

I've seen some people use the form `this.atts.description` before but this does not work either. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `this.atts.name`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the double quotes.

```
name=this.current.description
```